# Finding $\mathbb{E}[X^s e^{tX}]$ where $X \sim \mathrm{Gamma} (\alpha, \beta)$

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

**Question**

Find $\mathbb{E}[X^s e^{tX}]$, where $X \sim \mathrm{Gamma} (\alpha, \beta)$ and $\alpha$, $\beta$ are the shape and scale parameters respectively. Specify also the real values of $s$ and $t$ for which the required expectation exists.

**My working**

Let $Y \sim \mathrm{Gamma} (\alpha, 1)$, then $X = \beta Y$ and $f_Y(y) = \frac {y^{\alpha - 1} e^{-y}} {\Gamma(\alpha)}\ \forall\ y \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

$\begin{aligned}[t]
\mathbb{E}[X^s e^{tX}] & = \mathbb{E}[(\beta Y)^s e^{t\beta Y}]
\\[1 mm] & = \beta^s \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} y^s e^{t\beta y} f_Y(y)\ \mathrm{d}y
\\[1 mm] & = \frac {\beta^s} {\Gamma(\alpha)} \int^{\infty}_{0} y^{\alpha - 1 + s} e^{\left(t\beta - 1\right)y}\ \mathrm{d}y
\end{aligned}$

However, this is where I am stuck. I am having difficulty in evaluating the integral and finding the values of $s$ and $t$ for which there is convergence. I have tried relating the integral to the gamma function, but to no avail, in particular because of the exponential term in the integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to just evaluate the integral?

$$\int_0^\infty y^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta y}dy=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\beta^\alpha}$$ so

$$\int_0^\infty y^{\alpha+s-1}e^{(t\beta-1)y}dy=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+s)}{(1-t\beta)^{\alpha+s}}$$

It must be that

$$\alpha+s>0\rightarrow s>-\alpha\\
1-t\beta>0\rightarrow t<\frac 1 \beta$$

Comment: Oh... you can do that? Yeah I suppose there’s no reason why you cannot. I wonder why, for some reason, I thought that only the power of $x$ can vary, but not the coefficient of $x$ in the exponential term. Silly me. Thank you for the help nonetheless!

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. The shape and scale/rate must be greater than 0. I didn’t check for correctness of your previous work though

Comment: I see. Yes I re-posted my comment after you had made an edit to your answer including the ranges for $s$ and $t$, which confirmed my own answer!

Answer (score 1):

If $\beta$ is supposed to be the "scale parameter" the density is the following.

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}\beta^{\alpha}}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}$$

thus  your expectation is

$$\mathbb{E}[X^s e^{tX}]=\frac{\Gamma{(a+s)}}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}\beta^{\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{\beta}-t\right)^{\alpha+s}}\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{\beta}-t\right)^{\alpha+s}}{\Gamma{(a+s)}}x^{[(\alpha+s)-1]} e^{-(1/\beta-t)x}dx}_{=1}$$

---

further details on the solution

$$\mathbb{E}[X^s e^{tX}]=\frac{1}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}\beta^{\alpha}}\int_0^{\infty}x^{[(\alpha+s)-1]} e^{-(1/\beta-t)x}dx$$

Observe that the integrand is the kernel of a Gamma distribution with different parameter that you can easy recognize. Thus all you have to do is to fit the integrand with the missing parmeters' expressions and if you muliply for something, in the meantime divide out of the integral for the same quantity...very very easy

Using the definition of [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) you can immediately specify the parameters' range

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have two queries. Firstly, why do you say my density function is wrong? Following yours, if I let $\beta = 1$, I would get my density function, isn’t it? Secondly, how do you tell at a glance that the integral you wrote equals $1$? I notice this is a “trick” my professor uses a lot too, but I am still having some difficulty in seeing the form.

Comment: @EthanMark:  I beg your pardon but I supposed you defined $f_X(x)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x\beta}$...Answer amended but the result is the same

Comment: No I did not. In fact, I chose not to define $f_X(x)$ at all, but rather, to define $X$ in terms of a new random variable $Y$. The $\beta^s$ which you see outside of my integral comes merely from the direct expansion of the required expectation.

Comment: @EthanMark: the integral is 1 because I recognized the kernel of a gamma thus all you have to do is to fit it with the remaining "normalizing constants"

Comment: @EthanMark : I added some futher useful details....

Comment: I see. So just to check if I am understanding this “trick” correctly, the integrand, in your answer, is the kernel of a random variable distributed as $\mathrm{Gamma} (\alpha + s, \frac 1 {\beta} - t)$ using shape and scale parameters right?

Comment: @EthanMark $(1/\beta-t)$ is the rate parameter in my density. I prefer this kind of parametrization but if you prefer the other one you can do that, modifying the parameter accoringly

Comment: Right. Sorry, just one more question, as I am still very unfamiliar with the gamma function having been exposed to it just recently - is it possible to further simplify $\frac {\Gamma(\alpha + s)} {\Gamma(\alpha)}$?

Comment: @EthanMark no, in general it is not possible.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your help!